# PHP abstract class for populating a class from database table

Tags: php, oop

Currently I have a class DailyRecord for a table in my database, daily_record.  Let's say it has fields named id, field1, and field2.  In my constructor I pass in the record ID and query the database to retrieve all three fields. I want my class to have data members that are populated from this query.

However, I will be doing this with many tables and classes and I am trying to avoid something like this:

```
public __construct($id){
    //$record = $db->query('some query here');

    $this->id = $record['id'];
    $this->field1 = $record['field1'];
    $this->field2 = $record['field2'];
}
```

Because if I have many fields in the table this will get quite tedious.  Additionally, I may not need to fill all of the fields every time I create the class (if I use multiple constructors).  I thought I remember seeing an eCommerce CMS (Prestashop or Magento) that created an abstract class for this.  Somehow by extending this abstract class, it was possible to automatically populate these fields.

What can I use for something like this?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't query the DB inside of the ctor. What if there is an exception? What if the database is closed? etc. What if your datasource changes? Use an interface to define how the class interacts with any ambiguous data source, then dependency inject an instance of that interface into a `load` method.

Comment: Good point.  So even if I move this querying outside of the ctor I would like to find a way to automatically populate fields.

Comment: You could start by using `DESCRIBE tableName` in order to get the all the information you need in fields and field types for MySQL and `sp_columns` for MSSQL, etc

Comment: Multiple constructors? In PHP?

Comment: I am not aware of any issues throwing an Exception inside a ctor in php. Nevertheless, Injecting the data connector instead of init it inside the class, either to the ctor or a load method, is good practice.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka It's generally not considered good practice for a ctor to throw any exceptions, at least, from what I've read.

Comment: @crush I have read that sentiment, although, never so a convincing explanation. Without sarcasam, if u know of a good explanation, pls put a link

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka The explanations hinge on the idea that objects should never fail on creation. Also, you can create the object outside the scope of a try/catch instead.

Comment: @crush I guess as long as your code is consistent, it is ok to do it that way. *the idea that objects should never fail on creation* is just that, an idea, not the reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public __construct($id){
    $record = SOME_DATASTORAGE_CONTAINER->query('some query here');
    foreach($record as $k=>$v){
        $this->$k = $v;
    }
}
```

You can also [read](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) about the `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` way of fetching data

Comment: Doesn't `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` require the fields to be public accessibility, or no?

Comment: they will be public, u do not need to define them though. PHP is not perfect ;-)

Comment: So, PHP will create the members if they do not exist?

Comment: yep, this is general PHP behavior. U can always create members on the fly.

Comment: Since this Q was bumped from the attic -> this answer no longer demonstrates correct approach as [Dynamic properties are deprecated as of PHP 8.2.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dynamic_properties)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski careful there - plenty of people are on older versions and can't upgrade easily - U can edit tags to specify the right versions